# How to get the SQL statement behind the Query Store results (sys.query_store_*)

Tags: sql-server

This question is about querying the `sys.query_store_*` tables. The SQL Server interface lets you build reports for "Top Resources Consuming Queries" (part of the Query Store feature).

I created a report that I like. Now, how can I view the underlying SQL statement(s) to produce this data. I want to build my own automated report based on that and I'd like to use this view's statement as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Sql Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017) while you are running the report to capture the SQL Statements.

Comment: one comment - the view itself queries internal objects, so you can't necessarily query internal tables directly without going through views defined in the resource database in SQL Server/SQL Azure.  However, the query against the view is captured in the query store and you can just go get those if you are looking for queries generated by the SSMS UI or similar layers on top of the query store